# using urn:helper in xsl

Tags: xslt

I'm new to xslt. I tried using urn:helper in the stylesheet tag. But it throws the following error.
"Cannot find the script or external object that implements prefix 'urn:Helper'".

Below is the snippet used in my code.

```
xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:myObj="urn:Helper"
xmlns:t="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006"
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks..

edit: complete stylesheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:myObj="urn:Helper"
xmlns:t="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2006">
  <xsl:param name="today"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="results"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="pass" select="'Passed'"/>
  <xsl:param name="fail" select="'Failed'"/>
  <xsl:key name="class-key" match="@className" use="."/>
  <xsl:variable name="unique-classes" select="//t:TestMethod/@className[generate-id(.) =generate-id(key('class-key',.))]" />  
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <html>
      <body style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt">
        <h1>Test Results Summary</h1>
            <table style="font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt">
      <tr>
        <td>
          <b>Run Date/Time</b>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          Start Time:
        </td>
        <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="myObj:DateTimeToString(//t:TestRun/t:Times/@start)"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          End Time:
        </td>
        <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="myObj:DateTimeToString(//t:TestRun/t:Times/@finish)"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td>
          Duration: 
          </td>
          <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="myObj:TimeSpan(//t:TestRun/t:Times/@start,//t:TestRun/t:Times/@finish)"/>
        </td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <b>Results File</b>
        </td>
        <td>
              <xsl:value-of select="$results"/>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <a href="coverage.htm">Coverage Summary</a>
    <xsl:call-template name="summary" />
      <!--<xsl:call-template name="details" />-->
      <xsl:call-template name="details2" />
  </body>
</html>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="summary">
    <h3>Test Summary</h3>
    <table style="width:640;border:1px solid black;font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">Total</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">Failed</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">Passed</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">Inconclusive</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td >
      <xsl:value-of select="/t:TestRun/t:ResultSummary/t:Counters/@total"/>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:pink;">
      <xsl:value-of select="/t:TestRun/t:ResultSummary/t:Counters/@failed"/>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:lightgreen;">
      <xsl:value-of select="/t:TestRun/t:ResultSummary/t:Counters/@passed"/>
    </td>
    <td style="background-color:yellow;">
      <xsl:value-of select="/t:TestRun/t:ResultSummary/t:Counters/@inconclusive"/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="details">

<h3>Unit Test Results</h3>
<table style="width:640;border:1px solid black;font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt;">
  <tr>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">Test Name</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">Result</td>
    <td style="font-weight:bold">Duration</td>
  </tr>
  <xsl:for-each select="/t:TestRun/t:Results/t:UnitTestResult">
    <xsl:sort select="@testName"/>
    <tr>
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@outcome='Failed'">background-color:pink;</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@outcome='Passed'">background-color:lightgreen;</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>background-color:yellow;</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@testName"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@outcome='Failed'">FAILED</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@outcome='Passed'">Passed</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>Inconclusive</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@duration"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each>
</table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="details2">

<h3>Unit Test Results</h3>
<table border="0" style="width:640;border:1px solid black;font-family:Verdana; font-size:10pt;">
  <xsl:for-each select="$unique-classes">
    <xsl:sort />
    <xsl:variable name="curClass" select="."/>
    <xsl:variable name="return" select="myObj:GetClassInformation($curClass)"/>
    <!--<xsl:for-each select="//TestRun/tests/value/testMethod[className=$curClass]">-->

    <tr>
      <td valign="bottom" style="background-color:beige;font-weight:bold;" colspan="3">
        <font>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('',$return/className)"/>
        </font>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">Test Name</td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">Result</td>
      <td style="font-weight:bold">Duration</td>
    </tr>
      <xsl:for-each select="//t:UnitTest/t:TestMethod[@className=$curClass]">
      <xsl:sort select="@name"/>
      <xsl:variable name="testid" select="../@id"/>
      <xsl:for-each select="//t:UnitTestResult[@testId=$testid]">
        <xsl:call-template name="classRunsDetail">
        <xsl:with-param name="testid" select="."/>
      </xsl:call-template>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <tr>
      <td style="border-bottom:0px solid black;height:1px;background-color:black" colspan="3"></td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:for-each>
</table>      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="classRunsDetail">
    <xsl:param name="testid"/>
    <tr>
      <xsl:attribute name="style">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@outcome = $fail">background-color:pink;</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@outcome = $pass">background-color:lightgreen;</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>background-color:yellow;</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@testName"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="@outcome = $fail">FAILED</xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="@outcome = $pass">Passed</xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>Inconclusive</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="@duration"/>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Provide complete stysheet, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no problem with your `xsl:stylesheet` element.

The problem is here:

```
<xsl:value-of select="myObj:DateTimeToString(//t:TestRun/t:Times/@start)"/>
```

From http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#section-Extension-Functions

> If a FunctionName in a FunctionCall
>   expression is not an NCName (i.e. if
>   it contains a colon), then it is
>   treated as a call to an extension
>   function. The FunctionName is expanded
>   to a name using the namespace
>   declarations from the evaluation
>   context.
>
> If the XSLT processor does not have an
>   implementation of an extension
>   function of a particular name
>   available, then the function-available
>   function must return false for that
>   name. If such an extension function
>   occurs in an expression and the
>   extension function is actually called,
>   the XSLT processor must signal an
>   error.

The answer: **You are missing the extension function implementation**.

So, you must provide details of your processor and re-ask what is the specific way that your processor is linked to the implementation of extended functions.

Answer (score 0):

I see you grabbed that little helper object from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916532/xslt-line-counter-is-it-that-hard) post. It seems right, but make sure you are using the C# code to actually do the transform.

Comment: Well I'm actually working on an xsl that already exists. This file does not throw errors when running with the nightly builds on the build server.. But when I run it locally on my system, it throws the error.

Comment: @Sidd Then you don't have compiled and integrated on your local system the file that contains the implementation of the extension function. On the other side, this file *is* included in the build performed on the build server.