# How to get line number in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

Is it possible to get the line number when we apply XSLT to an XML? I need to know the line number when there is a particular template match found in the XML.

Is it possible to retrieve the line number?

Comment: Do you mean the line number within a single tag? Such as a `<text>` tag (containing only text), and you want to select the nth line of text? If so, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916532/xslt-line-counter-is-it-that-hard/2916978#2916978) might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

If you mean the line number of the node in the source document, Saxon provides this using an extension function [`saxon:line-number()`](http://www.saxonica.com/html/documentation/functions/saxon/line-number.html), provided the source document is supplied via an interface (e.g. a SAX parser) that reports line numbers. There's no standard XSLT mechanism for this.

Comment: saxon-line-number() requires Saxon-PE or Saxon-EE. Saxon-HE (the free version) doesn't support it.