# How can I identify line numbers in XSLT input or from XPath?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am processing XML files using an XSLT stylsheet and wish to report the input line number when a given template is triggered. I can use a DOM (e.g. XOM in Java)  which supports a SAX parser so maybe can use a Locator.

Alternatively the XSLT generates an Xpath which could be applied to the original document and so, at least for a human, can lead to the particular line.

(The actual application is to detect error conditions in the XML, which are searched for using XSLT)

Comment: There's a chance extension functions and/or elements could be of use, but it's a long shot.

Comment: @paulsm4 Thanks for the rapid reply. It is not inconceivable to create a hack - the template when triggered knows its Xpath and a DOM traversal knows its Xpath for each node and the SAX/Dom builder knows the line number. So one hack would be to add the line/column number as an attribute to the DOM. Tacky, so maybe there is a better way

Comment: Dimitre's answer in [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916532/xslt-line-counter-is-it-that-hard) seems interesting. Could be a starting point? EDIT: [yet more](http://www.xmlplease.com/linenumber)

Comment: If you want to detect error conditions in the .xml file why don't just use xsd?

Comment: @FailedDev because the XSLT is using templates to detect conditions beyond the scope of XSD (e.g. att1 must have a value between 1 and 4 and att2 must be absent) . We use XSD for the simpler stuff.

Comment: @FailedDev Because XSD is about as flexible as a bulkhead. That's why people came up with RELAX NG and Schematron.

Comment: @G_H many thanks. Both are excellent pointers. Dimitre's answer should just work by counting all the `preceding` line-feeds although there may be some nasty XML normalization which fouls this up. The XSLT solution might work, but I can't use XSLT2.0 for general distrib

Comment: Gah, lack of XSLT 2.0 support strikes again! Oh well...

Comment: @G_H I am a great supporter of Saxon so that if XSLT2.0 is the way to go I might just bundle it into the distro. But I would ideally like the solution to work "anywhere" (I am an optimist).

Comment: @FailedDev our approach is effectively a variant of Schematron

Comment: @peter.murray.rust: I see my name mentioned but I still don't understand the question and how any of my existing solutions contribute to this case. Could you, please, explain? If you need to produce an XPath expression that selects any given node, this *can* be done in XSLT 1.0.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev What the poster wants is to have the node location in the input file (line number, character offset, anything like that) available for output when a certain template is triggered by that node.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Saxon has an extension for this. You can set an option when building the source tree to maintain line number information (e.g. -l on the command line), and if this was set, you can use the extension function saxon:line-number() to get the line number associated with an element node in the tree.

Comment: @Mike many thanks. Is this callable programmatically from within Java? The application is sufficiently self-contained that I think I am happy to use an extension function

Comment: Insofar as Saxon's NodeInfo interface has a getLineNumber() method, yes, it's usable from Java. But of course Saxon's NodeInfo is not primarily designed for use by Java applications (it's designed for use by XSLT and XPath engines).